# Fix html printing content vertically centered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, printing

I have a simple html page written using bootstrap 4. This page's content is inside a container > row > col, and it looks good in most screens, but when I try to print it, it's vertically centered in the paper/PDF. How can I make this page's content go to the top of the paper in print layout?

[image: printng page in chrome]

Here's the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>my title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top .d-print-none">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
    aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/logo.png" alt="myalt" class="logoIMG"></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/workers">Add worker</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/workers/list">List workers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container mt-5">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img class="mb-4" src="/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 40%; height: auto;">
            </div>
            <h1>Checklist for new worker</h1>

            <ul>
                <li>lorem: lorem</li>
                <li>lorem: lorem</li>
                <li>lorem: lorem</li>
            </ul>

             <h3>lorem</h3>
             <ul>
                 <li>lorem: lorem</li>
             </ul>
             <h3>lorem</h3>
             <ul>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem Quick lorem</li>
            <li>lorem</li>
            <li>lorem lorem (only lorem)</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</main>
<style>
     .logoIMG {
       height: 2rem;
       width: auto;
     }

 </style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    html,
    body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: What the thinking behind having `<style>` tags inside the `<body>`? The only valid place for a `<style>` tag is within `<head>`. See [<style>: The Style Information element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

Comment: Sorry, it's a combination of me not knowing standards and not using some slot feature in my rendering engine, in order to put the style in the head. I'll fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `align-items: center` property for the body tag. Removing it fixed the situation. Of course it was there for a reason, but I changed the property only for the pages I needed to print correctly.
I could also use a `@media print { body { align-items: strech !important; } }` , or similar, so it was only applied to printing situations.